# How do I get python to recognize a module from any directory?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, package, pydicom

I'm installing some additional packages to anaconda and I can't get them to work. One such package is pydicom which I downloaded, unziped, and moved to `/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-package/pydicom`. In the pydicom folder the is a subfolder called `source` which contains both `ez_setup.py` and `setup.py`. I ran `sudo python setup.py install` which didn't spit out any errors and then ran `sudo python ez_setup.py install` when I still couldn't get the module to open in ipython. Now I can successfully `import dicom` but ONLY when my current directory is `/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-package/pydicom/source`. How do I get it so I import it from any directory? I'm running CentOS and I put

`export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/:$PATH`
in my .bashrc file.

Comment: Don't install archives manually. Use `pip install </path/to/archive>` instead.

Comment: When I try that I get this error: `Command /usr/local/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_gcw8/pydicom/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TdTVZf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_gcw8/pydicom
Storing debug log for failure in /PHShome/gcw8/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: What is the error message in the /PHShome/gcw8/.pip/pip.log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't copy the source to site-packages directly. Rather, use `python setup.py install` in the source directory, or use `pip install .`. Make sure your Python is indeed the one in `/usr/local/anaconda`, especially if you use sudo (which in general is not necessary and not recommended with Anaconda).